# VBA - Set Property in Subroutine to Automatically Step Over While Debugging

Tags: vba, debugging

This question is specifically regarding the property get/let code in a class module but I think that the solution will be applicable to any subroutine.

There must be a property that tells vba to step over a function in break mode automatically (even when pressing the step into key/F8). Obviously such a thing exists for built in VB subs, classes and functions since the debugger doesn't step into them but I can't find a way to apply it to my code. What is it?!

It will make my life much easier when debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>, there is also a button on the Debug toolbar.

[image]

---

Bonus Round:

If you forget to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and end up inside of the class anyway, you can Step *Out* by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>

And go backwards by right clicking on the line you want to go back to and selecting "Set Next Statement".

---

One last note, the reason the debugger doesn't step into the "built in" classes is because that code is not written in VBA. It is hidden behind the COM Interop wall and written in an entirely different language all together.

Comment: You can also drag the yellow arrow in the left margin within the procedure you're in, instead of "Set next statement"

Comment: I'm familiar with the step into, step over and step out functionality of the debugger. If your answer to my question is "no it can't be done" then please state that and I will mark this as the best answer.

Comment: Then your question is a bit unclear @RichardFoxton. What exactly do you want then?

Comment: I think he wants it to automatically `Ctrl-F8` when he hits `F8` and it's stepping into a class module, or in particular a Get/Set function. I agree that this would be a particularly awesome function to have, but M$ would have to invest some bux into the IDE to make it happen.

Comment: I want a way to flag a subroutine / set a property in a subroutine so that the debugger will not step into the code even when the debugger is told to step into it. Rather it will function as if the debugger was told to step over the sub. (What FreeMan said)

Comment: @RichardFoxton that's not any clearer. Stepping over a procedure is done manually with the *step over* command in all IDE's I've worked with. Or you can F9-breakpoint *after* the procedure you want to skip and press F5 to let it run to the next breakpoint.

Comment: Yeah. Given that, you can't @RichardFoxton. Not unless you want to build your own IDE from scratch. Even the Mug and I aren't *that* crazy.

Comment: Fair enough. Consider this answered.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you're asking, you need to *step over* instead of *step into*.

Try <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> instead of just <kbd>F8</kbd>.